# Prolite 3493 HDMI inputs

Tags: windows-7

Just bought myself a shiny new Prolite 3493 widescreen monitor with the intention of using it for both my desktop pc and work laptop.  Problem one is that I can only use either HDMI 1 or 2, when the PBP option is selected I can then only use HDMI2 input which defeats the whole reason for buying it.
Is the monitor capable of HDMI's only or does it have to have displayport as the main input with the HDMi as the second?

Answer (score 0):

The manual is downloadable from manufacturer website and contains a list of combinations that are possible.

Using two HDMI inputs simultaneously is not possible.

Using DP and one of the HDMI inputs simultaneously is possible.

Comment: Thanks Justme, I have just seen that.  Botherations, means I shall have to get a new PC!